# Vimeo Feed gived dead link with RSS widget?

Tags: widgets, rss

I have RSS widget on my [home page](http://www.dekho.com.au/) (footer) pointing to a [RSS feed](http://vimeo.com/user3235740/videos/rss) from Vimeo.

The videos pull in fine, and the links for these work.
The orange RSS icon also takes you to the actual RSS feed.

However, the title takes you to a [404](http://vimeo.com/user3235740/videos/uploaded).

I am not sure if this is a fault of how Vimeo is setup, or the widget.

Can anyone think of a workaround to ensure this title is not a dead link?

This short [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/yTYMW1eXlCc) explains the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the title comes from the RSS feed: it contains a `<link>` element describing the URL of the entire channel. I think Vimeo (recently?) changed their URL structure so `http://vimeo.com/user3235740/videos/uploaded` no longer points to the recently uploaded videos, but `http://vimeo.com/user3235740/videos/sort:newest` does.

It looks like Vimeo should update their feeds to include the correct URL. The default RSS widget does not allow you to change the URL easily, so I suggest you duplicate this widget code and add a fix for the URL yourself.